# Can i read the logged in user name in nifi processor or any component?

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to know, can i read the logged in user via nifi interface or the user who configured the processor in the onTrigger method or any other way that i can access the user information in nifi? or can i access from any context service by tweaking the code?

Comment: not sure this will help.. there is a rest  api /flow/history/components/{componentId}

Comment: This works when we try to access processor information externally via API, but I would like to know how to access user  information while the processor is running(onTrigger) or on Startup(init)  or onscheduled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A processor should not need to know anything about a user who accessed the NiFi web UI.

A user configures and starts a processor, but once the processor is running NiFi has no idea (nor should it) about the user that started that processor.

The processor runs on behalf of the NiFi framework, and some processors allow providing an identity to interact with external systems. For example, processors that authenticate to an external system via Kerberos will take a principal and keytab, they run as the principal when interacting with the external system.

Comment: Thanks @bryan-bende, it don't  access user info as per nifi architecture, but  i  want to know does it possible to access user who created the processor from Context or Process Session Object or any other with in Processor or Controller Service or in any component

Comment: It is not possible, NiFi is not keep tracking of the last user that configured a processor, each request is authorized and once the request is complete the knowledge of that user is gone. Is there a use case you have in mind that requires knowing that?

Comment: Yes I have gone through NIFI code but directly it's not checking, but I need the user who has configured or who has accessed the interface and data being captured and gets updated into the data flown through the processor, but just a try to know if someone from community  tried accessing it

Comment: Can you describe why your processor needs to know about a user? There are no plans to make this information available to a processor.

Comment: Apologies its business case and i cannot share and thanks for letting me knowing it